# How to populate Grid with ajax where data coming from REST API JSON format?

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, rest, datatable

> I am having an issue, i got JSON format data from backend in this
>   format, and i am having trouble fetching data to table.

**>JSON Format:**

```
    {
    "success": true,
    "code": "200",
    "message": "successfull",
    "response": {
        "A00XYZ": [
            {
                "9": "30.00",
                "26": "43.01",
                "36": "632.56",
                "39": "56.82",
                "58": "13.12",
                "65": "292.73",
                "148": "0.00",
                "393": "1.96",
                "472": "64.17",
                "517": "0.00",
                "firstName": "jhon",
                "lastName": "ends"
            }
        ],
        "A00XYZ2": [
            {
                "9": "21.26",
                "26": "78.19",
                "36": "1003.91",
                "39": "65.73",
                "58": "78.65",
                "65": "23.00",
                "148": "0.00",
                "393": "2.40",
                "472": "55.84",
                "517": "34",
                "firstName": "Dummy",
                "lastName": "Knight"
            }
        ]
}
```

> I have tried few approaches. There are still some issues arising.

**> Jquery:**

```
if(data.response == 200){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data.response[i]) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.response[i][key].length; j++) {
            console.log(data.response[i][key][j])
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have missed is you need to get the first element of `data.response[i]`.

Try this here, is this what you after?

```
    var result = {}
    $.each(data.response, function(key) {
      result[key] = {}
      $.each(data.response[key][0], function(e) {
        result[key][e] = data.response[key][0][e];
      })
    })
```

```js
var data = {
        "success": true,
        "code": "200",
        "message": "successfull",
        "response": {
            "A00XYZ": [
                {
                    "9": "30.00",
                    "26": "43.01",
                    "36": "632.56",
                    "39": "56.82",
                    "58": "13.12",
                    "65": "292.73",
                    "148": "0.00",
                    "393": "1.96",
                    "472": "64.17",
                    "517": "0.00",
                    "firstName": "jhon",
                    "lastName": "ends"
                }
            ],
            "A00XYZ2": [
                {
                    "9": "21.26",
                    "26": "78.19",
                    "36": "1003.91",
                    "39": "65.73",
                    "58": "78.65",
                    "65": "23.00",
                    "148": "0.00",
                    "393": "2.40",
                    "472": "55.84",
                    "517": "34",
                    "firstName": "Dummy",
                    "lastName": "Knight"
                }
            ]
         }
    };
    
    var response = data.response;
    var result = {}
    $.each(response, function(key) {
      result[key] = {}
      $.each(response[key][0], function(e) {
        result[key][e] = response[key][0][e];
      })
    })
    console.log(result)
```